# SQL RIGHT function not working as expected

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to extract the month number from a date as a left padded string with 0's.

So, for example, from `'2018-01-31'` I want the string `'01'`.

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH('2018-01-31') AS CHAR(2)), 2)
```

Which is returning `'1'` but I would have expected it to return `'01'` because I've provided the second argument to `RIGHT` as `2`.

Could someone explain why this isn't working as I think it should?

Comment: FYI SQL 2012+ - format() can do this if you specify 'MM'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `CHAR` to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH('2018-01-31') AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a72680d2d47b553e3b15ce07bca01a5)**

`CHAR(2)` is blank padded so you get `RIGHT('01 ',2)` which is `'1 '`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, are you able to explain why it works for VARCHAR and not for CHAR?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) instead, when you first cast the string to a DATE type.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2018-01-31' as DATE),'MM')
```

As for why that SQL with the right didn't work?

Try this SQL and notice the difference (the extra space):

```
SELECT quotename('0' + CAST(1 AS CHAR(2))), quotename('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)))
```